# Does RxDart support back pressure?

Tags: dart, rxdart

When there is a fast producer and slow consumer, I want to replace all old waiting emissions with the newest one - something similar to RxJava's [Emitter.BackpressureMode.LATEST](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/index.html?rx/Emitter.BackpressureMode.html)

[image]

Is there any way to achieve this in RxDart or Dart Streams?

Answer (score 0):

Hi it seems like I'm too late)

But maybe it will help someone else
For back pressure in rxDart there is the Debounce method.

Example:

```
subject.debounce(new Duration(milliseconds: 500)).listen((s) => print(s));
```

More info:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u9VgxH-X_7s

Comment: Debounce will not work as a replacement for backpressure, you will lose items.

>The Debounce operator filters out items emitted by the source Observable that are rapidly followed by another emitted item.

https://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/debounce.html